# How to listen changes inside TextController?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX. I need to listen changes in TextController. The follow code do not work:

```
class Controller extends GetxController{

  final txtList = TextEditingController().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    debounce(txtList, (_) { 
      print("debouce$_");
      }, time: Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.onInit();
  }

}
```

Is does not print nothing when I am changing `txtList` value from UI. I suppose it's because it does not check text field inside `txtList`.

How to get it work?

Comment: TextEditingController().obs wont work! either you use onchange property of textfield or you add a listener to the controller on Init and try printing.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali, could you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an `RxInterface` into `debounce` to do this via GetX. Just create an `RxString` and add a listener to the controller then pass the `RxString` into `debounce`.

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  final txtList = TextEditingController();

  RxString controllerText = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    txtList.addListener(() {
      controllerText.value = txtList.text;
    });
    
    debounce(controllerText, (_) {
      print("debouce$_");
    }, time: Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Then on any page in the app you can pass in that controller into the textfield and it'll print the value after the user stops typing for 1 second.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
 final controller = Get.put(Controller());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(controller: controller.txtList), // this will print
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if you need that value for anything else it's also always accessible via `controller.controllerText.value`.

Answer (score 1):

1. By `TextEditingController.text`, we can already get changing text input value so it does not need `.obs`.
2. To pass parameter for `debounce`, we should pass value itself : `txtList.text`. (see here: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md)

```
final txtList = TextEditingController(); // 1. here

  @override
  void onInit() {
    debounce(txtList.text, (_) {  // 2. here
      print("debouce$_");
     }, time: Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.onInit();
  }
```

This might work.

=================== added 11/21 ==================

Here's the example. I know the `RxString` variable seems a duplication for `TextEditingController.text`, but GetX's `debounce` function needs `RxString` type variable as a parameter. I tried to find more elegant way to do this, but I couldn't find anything. Please let me know if somebody knows a better way.

```
// in controller

  late final TextEditingController textController;
  final RxString userInput = "".obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    textController = TextEditingController();
    userInput.value = textController.text;

    textController.addListener(() {
            userInput.value = textController.text;
        }
    );

    
    debounce(userInput, (_) {
      print("debouce$_");
     }, time: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error: `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RxInterface<Object?>'`

Comment: Sorry. You might need to define `RxString` type variable and use it instead of `txtList.text`.

Comment: but my type is `TextEditingController`, not `RxString`. `TextEditingController` is needed for controller of surch type. Could you show me full example.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I edited my answer with example. @DmitryBubnenkov

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet for example to listen to `TextEditingController` text change listener

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() async {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: const HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller.addListener(_printLatestValue);
      }

      void _printLatestValue() {
        print('Second text field: ${controller.text}');
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: but how to get work `debounce`?

Comment: if you want debounce we have you have to use `rxdart`

Comment: but is it possible to get it work only with GetX?

Comment: @HemanhS GetX does in fact have a `debounce` method it's not necessary to use `RxDart` directly.